# Default in Switch running at the start

Tags: c, switch-statement, default

(Code is in C)

For some reason, my code always executes whats listed in the "default" section right before the menu is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){    
double funds=0; //initial funds
double donation=0; //donation to funds
double investment=0; //amount invested
int choice=0; //for the switch
int countdonate=0; //counts number of donations
int countinvest=0; //counts number of investments

printf("How much money is in the fund at the start of the year? \n");
scanf("%lf", &funds);//sets initial funds


while (choice!=4)

{

    switch (choice)

    { case 1: //option for donating
        printf("How much would you like to donate? \n");
        scanf("%lf", &donation);
        funds=funds+donation;
        countdonate++;
        break;

     case 2: //option for investing
        printf("How much would you life to invest? \n");
        scanf("%lf", &investment);
        if (investment>funds){
            printf("You cannot make an investment of that amount \n");
            break;}
        else{
            funds=funds-investment;
            countinvest++;
            break;}

     case 3: //prints current balance, number of donations, and number of investments
        printf("The current balance is %.2lf \n", funds);
        printf("There were %d donation(s) and %d investment(s) \n", countdonate, countinvest);
        break;


     default: //if the user selections something that isnt listed
            printf("why is this printing \n");
            break;
    }


    //displays list of options
    printf("What would you like to do? \n1 - Make a donation \n2 - Make an investment \n3 - Print balance of fund \n4 - Quit \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    //quit option, outside of the loop.
    //prints current balance, number of donations, number of investments, and ends the program
    if (choice==4)
       {printf("The current balance is %.2lf \n", funds);
        printf("There were %d donation(s) and %d investment(s) \n", countdonate, countinvest);
       }

}

return 0;
}
```

So when I run this for the first time, it prints:

---

How much money is in the fund at the start of the year? 
1000 (I input an integer)
why is this printing (This is in the default section and shouldn't be printing)
What would you like to do? 
1 - Make a donation 
2 - Make an investment 
3 - Print balance of fund 
4 - Quit

---

How do I fix this?

Comment: choice == 0 before the loop, and you don't read in anything to reset it, so the switch statement goes to the default case.

Answer (score 0):

Initial choice value is 0 and so the switch statement is printing what you are not expecting. To fix this, you should move the switch below as shown. Also add the break inside if (choice == 4).

```
//quit option, outside of the loop.
//prints current balance, number of donations, number of investments, and ends the program
if (choice==4)
   {printf("The current balance is %.2lf \n", funds);
    printf("There were %d donation(s) and %d investment(s) \n", countdonate, countinvest);
    break;
   }

switch (choice)
...
```